# Using I2C with the SenseHat

Tags: i2c, sense-hat

I'm working on a project that involves getting data from a SenseHat and transferring it via I2C to a arduino. I have managed to get the RPI and Arduino communicate without the sensehat but as soon as it goes on it does not work. I know that the SenseHat uses I2C to communicate with it's sensors but based on info from https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat# it should be working fine (I'm using different I2C addresses). In this case the RPI is the master and the arduino is the slave.

Comment: Anyone know of a way to do this?